# GCC: How to enable specific compilation warnings and disable rest

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

I am working witn gcc verisons 5.4.0 and 9.2.0. While compiling C/CPP code, I am unable to turn on specific warning message and disable all of the rest. I wanted to show missing return statement warning as errors and want to disable all other possible warnings.

For this I am running my gcc command with arguments as: `-Werror=return-type -w`. But looks like if we used `-w` then gcc not ownering other argument. Also tried running with arguments as:  `-Werror=return-type -w -Wreturn-type`  This also tunring off all the warnings even return-type warning.
Is there any way I could enable warning generated by `-Wreturn-type` and disable rest of others.

Comment: Try reversing the order to `-w -Werror=return-type`?  Or try not using `-w` — you want warnings so you can fix the bugs in your code.  I use `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` as a bare minimum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Reversing the order does not have any effect. In my case I only want to enable return-type warning that too as error. And disable every other possible warnings.

Comment: I get the impression you've demonstrated that it can't be done.