# GCC: How to customising warning and errors generated from compilation

Tags: c++, c, gcc, return-type, gcc-warning

**My Usecase:**
I have two c language files: `ApplicationCode.c` and `UserCode.c` . Application code is something generated by my app and UserCode is available to my application user where he can write his own code.
`ApplicationCode.c` internally uses `UserCode.c` and calls out its methods/function.

One thing you can assume here that `ApplicationCode.c` will never have any errors but could have warnings generated by gcc compiler. And `UserCode.c` can have both errors and warnings.
So, While compiling code I wanted to show user his code's errors as first priority. If needed to show warning also then show warning generated by his code only not from `ApplicationCode.c` (As i don't want to expose my `ApplicationCode.c`'s code).
One more constraint is here that I wanted to show return-type warning as error here and for this I am using `-Werror=return-type`  argument.

So, I am thinking of following three approaches to do this:

1. If I could able to disable all the warnings and enable only `-Wreturn-type`
   Raised a saparate question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66057711/gcc-how-to-enable-specific-compilation-warnings-and-disable-rest?noredirect=1#comment116793816_66057711)
2. If I could able to instruct gcc (or redirect) only error messages to stderr and rest on stdout.
   Raised a saparate question for this also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058810/gcc-how-to-force-gcc-compiler-to-print-warning-messages-on-stdout?noredirect=1#comment116793522_66058810)
3. If I could able to disable all the warnings (which are enabled by default) from `ApplicationCode.c` file and enable all with `-Werror=return-type`  for `UserCode.c`

I tried searching everywhere but did not get any solution for all the above 3. Let me know how could I achieve above problems or if there any other better way to do solve my use case ?

**Update 1:**
Here is my both the code file look like

ApplicationCode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// some headers
// some application specific code

int testUserFunction(); // user function declaration

int main(int argc, char *a[]) {
   int result  = testUserFunction(); // calling user function

   // some logic to use and evaluate result
}
```

UserCode.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int testUserFunction(int input1)
{
    // user will write his code below this

    // user code
    
}
```

Base command to compile code:

```
gcc -o code.out ApplicationCode.c UserCode.c
```

Comment: Re. `"As i don't want to expose my ApplicationCode.c's code"` -- but they're compiling it.  How are they doing that if they don't have the file available?

Comment: @G.M. please check update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or if there any other better way to do solve my use case ?

If you don't want to "expose ApplicationCode.c", then why are you showing its compilation output in the first place? Solution: Compile it in somewhere secret and let the user link their UserCode.c with it.

Comment: @AayushJain You can compile your module into a library that your user needs to link. This library can even include `main()`. This way you can enhance your source by separating it into modules, if applicable.

Comment: How can i keep compiled Application.c file ? If I simply compile using ```gcc -o code.out ApplicationCode.c```  then it will gives error that ```undefined reference to `testUserFunction' ```

Comment: @thebusybee @eerorika your comment helped me a lot. I used the ```-c``` switch while compiling like this: First I run ```gcc -c ApplicationCode.c -w``` then ```gcc -c code.out UserCode.c ApplicationCode.o -Werror=return-type``` . By this way I am getting expected results. Let me know if this is correct ? But just curious if this can be done in single gcc command ?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot apply different warning options to multiple sources **in one command line**.